# Why do I get the wrong path with sql-sync on windows using cygwin?

Tags: drush

I have drush 8 up and running ok on windows 10 with cygwin, except for running an sql-sync command.
When running the command to sync from stag(remote) to dev(local), it generated the dump file on the remote server fine but then has a problem pulling it down to my local machine.
Adding the -verbose option to the sql-sync command reveals that the path that it tries to put the database dump file is wrong.
eg.
`/cygdrive/C/wamp/www/kev//cygdrive/C/Users/2pha/AppData/Local/Temp`
as you can see the path is wrong.

```
You will delete files in /cygdrive/C/wamp/www/kev//cygdrive/C/Users/2pha/AppData/Local/Temp/kev_stag_20170123_095407.sql
.gz and replace with data from twopha@XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:/home/twopha/drush-backups/kev_stag/20170123095407/kev_stag_2017012
3_095407.sql.gz
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
Calling system(rsync -e 'ssh ' -akzv --exclude=".git" --exclude=".gitignore" --exclude=".hg" --exclude=".hgignore" --exc
lude=".hgrags" --exclude=".bzr" --exclude=".bzrignore" --exclude=".bzrtags" --exclude=".svn" --stats --progress --remove
-source-files twopha@106.185.47.186:/home/twopha/drush-backups/kev_stag/20170123095407/kev_stag_20170123_095407.sql.gz /
cygdrive/C/wamp/www/kev//cygdrive/C/Users/2pha/AppData/Local/Temp/kev_stag_20170123_095407.sql.gz);
receiving incremental file list
rsync: change_dir#3 "/cygdrive/C/wamp/www/kev//cygdrive/C/Users/2pha/AppData/Local/Temp" failed: No such file or directo
ry (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(713) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

**Here is the relevant part of my aliases:**

```
$aliases['dev'] = array(
  'root' => 'C:/wamp/www/kev',
  'uri'  => 'localsite.dev',
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%dump-dir' => 'c:/wamp/tmp',
    '%files' => 'sites/default/files',
  ),
    'source-command-specific' => array (
    'sql-sync' => array (
      'no-cache' => TRUE,
        'create-db' => TRUE,
        'mode' => 'rultvz',
    ),
  ),
);

$aliases['stag'] = array (
  'uri' => 'xxx.xxx.com',
  'root' => '/var/www/xxx.xxx.com/public_html',
  'remote-user' => 'serveruser',
  'remote-host' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%dump-dir' => '/tmp',
    '%files' => 'sites/default/files',
  ),
  'source-command-specific' => array (
    'sql-sync' => array (
      'no-cache' => TRUE,
    ),
  ),
  // No need to modify the following settings
  'command-specific' => array (
    'sql-sync' => array (
      'sanitize' => TRUE,
      'no-ordered-dump' => TRUE,
      'structure-tables' => array(
       // You can add more tables which contain data to be ignored by the database dump
        'common' => array('cache', 'cache_filter', 'cache_menu', 'cache_page', 'history', 'sessions', 'watchdog'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

**EDIT**
Also, while running rsync to sync the files, the paths seems all messed up:
I ran:
`drush rsync @kev.stage:%files/ @kev.dev:%files`
And this is what I got (notice the paths):

```
You will delete files in /cygdrive/C/wamp/www/kev//cygdrive/C/wamp/www/kev/sites/default/files and replace with data fro
m @kev.stage:/cygdrive/C/wamp/www/kev//cygdrive/C/wamp/www/kev/sites/default/files/
```

So, as far as using drush (specifically sql-sync and rsync with cygwin)
Is there some setting I am missing in relation to the paths?
Has someone encountered this before?
Is this a Drush bug? (I did search the [issue queue](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues) but found nothing)

Drush issues that seem relevant:
[Drush is converting Cygwin paths unnecessarily. If Cygwin PHP is being used, paths *should not* be converted.](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1226)
[fix for use under cygwin's php](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/1391)

Comment: As a temporary solution, I have altered the `drush_sitealias_evaluate_path` function in drush/includes/sitealias.inc to look for 2 occurrences of /cygdrive `if(substr_count($site_alias_settings['evaluated-path'], '/cygdrive') > 1)` and if found remove everything before second occurrence `$site_alias_settings['evaluated-path'] = trim(substr($site_alias_settings['evaluated-path'], strrpos($site_alias_settings['evaluated-path'], '/cygdrive')));`. It works, but I feel dirty altering a drush function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug in third-party software that should be reported in the proper channel.

Comment: Is it a bug? I'm not sure if it is.

Comment: From the issues you linked, it has been considered a bug. If it wasn't a bug, Moshe Weitzman would have answered differently, for example saying _there is a setting you need to change_.